# ticker.FuncFormatter not applying tick labels, why?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm using the ticker.FuncFormatter to convert a time measured in seconds to H:M:S format for the X axis ticks.  However, the ticks continue to show the raw seconds which lead me to believe the ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter wasn't being used.  I then tried setting the major_formatter to NullFormatter() and the resulting chart does indeed show no values on the X axis ticks.  You can see in my code where I've commended out the NullFormatter I used for testing.

So I must be calling the ticker.FuncFormatter incorrectly or in the wrong place, but a couple hours of troubleshooting has yielded no fruit.  I'm hoping someone here has more experience with matplotlib and can see my error.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
import csv
import datetime

probe1 = [123, 128, 192, 178, 210, 223, 252, 268]
probe2 = [121, 135, 164, 212, 245, 298, 301, 303]
secs = [1, 1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 10800, 14403, 21645]

def hms(x, pos=None):
    td = datetime.timedelta(seconds = x)
    hours = int((td.days * 24))
    hoursPlus = int(td.seconds / 3600)
    hours = hours + hoursPlus
    minutes = int(((td.seconds - (hoursPlus * 3600)) / 60))
    seconds = int(td.seconds - (minutes * 60) - (hoursPlus * 3600))
    tickString = str(hours) + ":" + str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds)
    print(tickString)
    return tickString

formatter = plt.FuncFormatter(hms)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 7))
plt.plot(secs, probe1, label='Probe 1')
plt.plot(secs, probe2, label='Probe 2')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.text(secs[-1]+1, probe1[-1]+1, probe1[-1], fontsize=15)
plt.text(secs[-1]+1, probe2[-1]+1, probe2[-1], fontsize=15)


plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.ylabel('Temp (F)')
plt.title('Temp History')
plt.legend(loc=2)

mpld3.save_html(fig, "test_example2.html")
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Bazingaa thx for the pointer, code example minimized

Comment: Again, please copy your code as it is right now in your question and paste it in a fresh new python editor/notebook. Then execute it. If it runs, then it is a MCVE. If not, then update your question with a MCVE.

Comment: Alright, code updated to MCVE

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/qgum0px) is what I am getting. The x-axis ticks are indeed in HH:MM;SS format. Click on the image in the link to enlarge it